# AFNetworking HTTPClient receiving 406 from a Rails JSON service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby

I'm building an iOS app to consume a web service that's offered up by a Rails 3.x application; specifically, I'm looking to receive a JSON response from a controller responds to a simple `GET` request with this block.

```
# after some data calls...

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => some_object }
  format.xml { render :xml => some_object }
end
```

In my iOS application, I'm using the `AFNetworking` library to create a subclass of an `AFHTTPClient` to consume this service. When I call my GET endpoint, I get an HTTP 406 error - and if I'm running this against the Rails app running locally, I can verify that's what's being sent. It runs through all the data calls successfully, it just seems to die once it gets to the `respond_to` block, and I'm pretty sure the problem is in the request headers that `AFNetworking` is sending.

Here's what my HTTP client is setting for its headers.

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

My endpoint is this...

```
http://localhost:3000/api/some_object.json
```

If I call this endpoint in my browser, it *renders just fine*. If I call it with my iOS app, then I get the 406. When I throw a breakpoint into my Rails app and inspect what headers are coming through, `AFNetworking` seems to be setting `request.format` to `mobile` — even though the `format` should be `.json` (like the URL suggests). From my browser, `request.format` is `application/json` like it should be.

I've tried manually setting this `format` option in my request in the URL, as a querystring param... and I'm stumped. Nothing works. Is there something I'm missing? Something I need to tell `AFNetworking` to use as a request header to get this to work? I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) source code and there is nowhere where the format is being set as `mobile`, the string doesn't even show up in the source once.

This must be happening on the Rails side. Are you defining any mobile Mime::Type aliases? Search your code for `mobile` to see what turns up. For a temp fix, I would just rewrite to

```
format.mobile { ... }
format.json { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, @coneybeare, and I think you're right - now that I think of it, there may be another plugin taking control of that format param if it's coming from an iOS device (mobile_fu perhaps; it's another dev's Rails app). I'll take a gander. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Also, when I throw in `respond.mobile`, the HTTP client expects to receive HTML for some reason. I'm betting it's `mobile_fu`.

Comment: The API controllers I had were inheriting from `ApplicationController` which had the `has_mobile_fu` declaration on it. Breaking that inheritance chain fixed it. Thanks for your help!